# Dijkstra-adding new verticle

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstra

I was writing code to solve problem of path to nearest shop in the city (I have a map of n vertices, some are houses and some are shops and I need to find the shortest path from each house to the shop) one idea is to add new vertice and connect it to every shop with edge of weight 0, then using Dijkstra get path from every house to this vertice, but as I was thinking I came up with another idea - what if instead adding new vertice I just put 0 in array of distances in indexes with shops and then use dijkstra? Will my distance array contain shortest path to shops from every house?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the idea you are looking for, is referred to as **SPDP** (**S**hortest **P**air **D**isjoint **P**ath). Generally, coming up with a general solution, is impossible with the outcoming algorithm probably **not** being **Greedy** (i.e. does **not** guarantee to attain the answer, even if there exists one). Different many paradigms can be deployed to use. For example, remove the links of each path you found from the network  (e.g. set their costs to a large enough number) and run Dijkstra's algorithm again. Repeat this step as long as you have obtained all the paths you want. Another methodology, comes from Bhandari's approach (or similarly Suurballe's approach). In this approach (which is used to derive two disjoint paths), the links of the first obtained path are reversed in direction and cost (i.e. the cost sign is swapped between + and -) though this approach requires Bellman-Ford's algorithm.